# Laravel 5 global settings

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I need to create some settings for controller method, accessible in view, for example: ajaxRefreshTime

Now, I found two ways:

1. Create config file, and use settings (set/get) in controller and view via Config facade
2. I can add some properties to the base controller, and in the constructor add it to view via View::share

May be there are more interesting ways?

Answer (score 1):

Normally the global settings are saved in `.env` file like

```
APP_NAME
DB_DATABASE
```

I think this is more a personal preference than a rule. You can save it in `app/config` also.

Comment: I change it in all controller methods, redefine, i think, it's not right way